# Loader during Unity IAP Callback

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to put loader in between dialog boxes come up for the purchase. What is the way for this?

Because when game player press **Buy** button, he should require to wait for 5 to 10 second depends on internet speed and server response and this process happed 2 to 3 times because multiple dialogs come up within screen.

So in this case, may be player can leave the screen. I want to put the loader so that game player realise that some processing is running in background, he required to wait for some time.

At present I was following completely this code for Unity IAP setup.
[Integrating Unity IAP In Your Game](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game)

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for mobile platform but even if its not still the following can be considered:

Simple solution is to create a full screen Image (UI/Panel) object in your UI to block clicks. I would use Animator component (with triggers) to display this panel in front of other UI when there is a background process running.

```c#
public class Loader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Loader Instance;
    Animator m_Animator;

    public bool Loading {get; private set;}

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this; // However make sure there is only one object containing this script in the scene all time. 
    }

    void Start()
    {
        //This gets the Animator, which should be attached to the GameObject you are intending to animate.
        m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        Loading = false;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Loading = true;
        m_Animator.SetBool("Loading", Loading); // this will show the panel.

    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        Loading = false;
        m_Animator.SetBool("Loading", Loading); // this will hide the panel.
    }
}
```

Then in any script which manipulates UI:

```c#
public void BuyButtonClicked()
{
    Loader.Instance.Show();
    // process time taking stuff
    Loader.Instance.Hide();    
}
```

You can also create any kind of loading animation as child of panel object using simple images and animation tool inside Unity (for example rotating animation (use fidget spinner, its cool)).

And in case of Android where user have option to leave screen by pressing OS back button you can prevent going back by checking if any loading is in progress by following example:

```c#
// code for back button
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
    { 
        BackButtonPressed(); 
    }
}

void BackButtonPressed()
{
    if(Loader.Instance.Loading)
        return;
    // use back button event. (For example to leave screen)
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Before and After purchase call, I can't put loader hide and show methods otherwise in single frame all things get happened because its not IEnumerator.

Comment: Obviously you are not supposed to do that. Its just an example just to give you an idea of where to call the methods. You can call both methods inside the coroutine accordingly

Comment: Brother this is not the exact reply so that I can make this as correct.

Comment: Did you even try the solution? I guess not. Being a little appreciative won't hurt. Not mentioning that someone spends their time to write a tutorial for an answer. Still **not exact reply**? Get someone to do the job for you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes @Umair M, I am not saying you have not done good thing by replying but if this is not a perfect answer then you can't force other person to mark this as correct. I can say above your point is 50% giving the direction. So always provide help to others if you have time because you are doing good job :)

Comment: I can provide you the exact solution link that I implemented so you can update your answer and after that I will make this correct because I definitely got hint from your reply what to do!!!

Comment: **this is not a perfect answer**? my friend this is the only answer you have received. Be grateful for this. Besides it doesn't say anywhere that acceptable answer should provide 100% solution to a problem described as "I WANT THIS, I WANT THAT". This kind of questions get down votes because the site is not about writing tutorials and doing job for you. To solve   your problem, even a small pointer is considered as helpful thus should be accepted as answer. Its not my concern which **tutorial** you have used in the end to do your job. Next time be careful about what kind of question you ask :)